# test if a listings or glossaries style is valid

Tags: listings, conditionals, glossaries

I want to test in my template if a call of

```
\lstinputlisting[style=mystyle,...
```

or

```
\printglossary[style=mystyle,...
```

is valid or will fail because of an unkown style.

However I could no find out in the sty files how these styles are saved and checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) defines an internal macro named `\@glsstyle@<style>` for each style `<style>`.

In case of [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) it's a little bit trickier than that. Basically `listings` defines a macro `\lststy@<style>$` for each style. However, `\lstdefinestyle` has an undocumented optional argument whose purpose is not quite clear to me. `\lstdefinestyle[foo]{mystyle}` would define a macro `\lststy@mystyle$foo`. I have never seen a use case for the optional argument before, though, and my (very superficial) tests didn't reveal how to load such a style, anyway.

Maybe something like the following would work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings,glossaries}

% ignore the optional argument:
\newcommand*\ifdeflststyle[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{lststy@#1$}}

\newcommand*\ifdefglsstyle[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{@glsstyle@#1}}

\begin{document}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{}
\ifdeflststyle{mystyle}{true}{false}     % => true
\ifdeflststyle{myotherstyle}{true}{false}% => false

\ifdefglsstyle{list}{true}{false}   % => true
\ifdefglsstyle{mystyle}{true}{false}% => false
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{}
\ifdefglsstyle{mystyle}{true}{false}% => true

\end{document}
```