# Conditional execution based on style existence (listings)

Tags: listings, conditionals

Is there a way in LaTeX (or e-TeX) to check if a style is defined using the `listings` package (inside a `\lstnewenvironment` definition)?

I mean something like this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{tmpdefaultstyle}{}
\lstdefinestyle{tmpstyle}{}
\lstnewenvironment{tmpenv}{
  \ifcsname **********\endcsname
    \lstset{style=tmpstyle}
  \else
    \lstset{style=tmpdefaultstyle}
  \fi
}{}
```

`**********` - I don't know what to write here.

Comment: Do you know a name that gets defined when you issue `\lstdefinestyle{tmpstyle}{}`?

Comment: Nope, that's the problem (question edited, thank you).

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95639/5049?

Comment: seems like it is... however the answer has some useful additional info (\tracingall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution.

With the help of `\tracingall` I've found that the command `\lstdefinestyle{<stylename>}{...}` generates a `lststy@<stylename>$` name 'on the fly'.

For instance, the command `\lstdefinestyle{tmpstyle}{...}` generates `lststy@tmpstyle$`.

So, the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lstdefinestyle{tmpdefaultstyle}{keywordstyle=\bfseries,language=[LaTeX]{TeX}}
\lstdefinestyle{tmpstyle}{keywordstyle=\ttfamily,language=[LaTeX]{TeX}}
\lstnewenvironment{tmpenv}{%
  \ifcsname lststy@tmpstyle$\endcsname%
    \lstset{style=tmpstyle}%
  \else%
    \lstset{style=tmpdefaultstyle}%
  \fi%
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tmpenv}
\documentclass{article}
\end{tmpenv}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

because the style `tmpstyle` is defined (and it is defined with `keywordstyle=\ttfamily`).

If you comment the line

```
\lstdefinestyle{tmpstyle}{keywordstyle=\ttfamily,language=[LaTeX]{TeX}}
```

then the style `tmpstyle` is not defined and you get

[image]

because this time the style `tmpdefaultstyle` is used (and it is defined with `\keywordstyle=\bfseries`).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Can you reference sg: how did you find out the name lststy@tmpstyle$ ? I could'nt find it yesterday... ("give a man a fish...")

Comment: @masu Search the log file for the 2nd occurrence of `\@namedef #1->\expandafter \def \csname #1\endcsname` and watch the lines that follow.